# How to test AFNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking, kiwi, nocilla, ohhttpstubs

***Edit - I originally wanted to test `AFNetworking` using `Nocilla` but ended up using `OHHTTPStubs` to do the job. I've answered the original question below, using `OHHTTPStubs` ***

Original Question:

I want to test the APIClient of our app - the bare bones of one of methods which needs to be tested is detailed below. So I need to mimic the `HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:` call from `AFNetworking`. `Nocilla` seems like an option to do this (more suitable than `OCMock`).
I've checked out [the github page](https://github.com/luisobo/Nocilla/blob/master/NocillaTests/Hooks/NSURLRequest/AFNetworkingStubbingSpec.m) which deals with `Nocilla` and `AFNetworking` but I'm not sure how to apply it to my problem - the syntax isn't very familiar.

- So my wondering if someone could give me a hint as to how I might use `Nocilla` in this case?
- Also, must one use `Kiwi` with `Nocilla`?

Thanks in advance :)

```
    -(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)getBroadcastsForChannel:(TINChannel *)channel
                                     startTime:(NSDate *)date
                                         limit:(NSNumber *)limit
                                     pastLimit:(NSNumber *)pastLimit
                                        fields:(NSArray *)fieldsArray
                                      interval:(TINBroadcastsInterval)interval
                               completionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *broadcasts, NSError *error))block {

    // Some setup here

    NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:params];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSError *error;

    NSDictionary *responseDic = [self parseResponse:responseObject error:&error];

        if (error) {
            if (block) {
                block([NSArray array], error);
            }
            return;
        }

        // Parse the response object here

        if (block) {
            block([NSArray arrayWithArray:broadcastsOutput], nil);
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    if (block) {
        block([NSArray array], error);
    }
    }];

        [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];

        return operation;

}
```

Comment: I was looking for an answer on this too!

Comment: I managed to get this working by using a different library - `OHHTTPStubs`. I'll post some sample code in a couple of hours when I get the chance.

Comment: @bilby91 I added some code, testing `AFNetworking` using `OHHTTPStubs`. Maybe this is of some use to to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem using another library, `OHHTTPStubs`. One can easily return mock objects through `AFNetworking`, stub out certain requests & vary response/ request times.
It is well documented [here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/OHHTTPStubs/2.0.0/Classes/OHHTTPStubs.html). Also here is the [github page](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs). A stub is removed like this:

```
[OHHTTPStubs removeStub:stub];
```

Here is some sample code:

```
// A mockJSON file is loaded here
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"sampleJSON18.json"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError* error = nil;
id mockJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

//*** stub out AFNetworkingRequestOperation and return custom NSDictionary "mockJSON", in order to see how it is handled
id<OHHTTPStubsDescriptor> stub = nil;
stub = [OHHTTPStubs stubRequestsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSURLRequest *request) {
    return [[request.URL path]isEqualToString:@"/v1/epg/packages/59/broadcasts"]; // this means that any request which is equal to the above string is stubbed, return YES to stub *all* requests
} withStubResponse:^OHHTTPStubsResponse*(NSURLRequest *request) {
    // The `stubbing` procedure occurs in this block.
    return [[OHHTTPStubsResponse responseWithJSONObject:mockJSON statusCode:200 headers:nil] requestTime:1.0f responseTime:5.0f]; // one can vary the request/responseTime here
}];

stub.name = @"getChannelsWithBroadcastsForDay";

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                  success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        // The response object is now the mockJSON object, i.e. the original request is stubbed out

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // handle failure
    }

        }];

    [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
    return operation;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest in `OHHTTPStubs`, I'm glad it's useful to you :) If you're new to it, I would strongly suggest you to directly use the latest version `3.x` to directly use the new and cleaner API ([see ChangeLog](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs/releases)). 
In particular, you could use `+responseWithFileAtPath:statusCode:headers:` + the `OHPathForFileInDocumentsDir(fileName)` macro ([see doc here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/OHHTTPStubs/3.0.2/Classes/OHHTTPStubsResponse.html#//api/name/responseWithFileAtPath:statusCode:headers:)) to avoid the first 6 lines of your code ;)

Comment: Yes many thanks it's been a great help :)
I wasnt aware there was a new version, I'll look into it.

Comment: Just a remark: if you want to store your stub in a `static` variable, you should either make it `__weak`, or don't forget to set it back to `nil` once you removed the stub, otherwise it will still be retained and won't clean the memory properly. (See the README about that; I improved the doc on GitHub's master branch some commits after tag `3.0.2` so it will only be included in doc for future 3.0.3, but you can directly read it on github directly). — 
PS: I'm not sure you can accept your own answer on SO, but if you can you should do it, to inform others that you have a working solution here.

Comment: I removed the `static`, I'd taken that code from an example & dont think it was really necessary for the purposes of demonstration. Also one can answers one's own question on SO I've done that. It might help someone out ;)

Comment: @MatterGoal OHHTTPStubs works with everything based on Apple's URL Loading System (NSURLSession, NSURLConnection, etc) so yes it works with AFN3 too.